# VBA Looking for fast thorough array shuffle algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, vba, optimization, shuffle

I'm looking for an algorithm of VBA code that shuffles an array thoroughly and quickly. (Running a card simulation for 1M hands)

(Details: I'm constructing a shoe of 104 cards (2 decks), playing one hand of blackjack, recording the results, then rebuilding and reshuffling the shoe for another hand. Repeating that process 1M times.)

The code I'm using now (found online) is returning non-random shuffles that skew the results. All other shuffle code I've found has just been a variation of this.

```
'shuffle
For N = 0 To N = UBound(shoe)
shoe(N) = N
Next

Randomize

For N = 0 To N = UBound(shoe)
X = Int(Rnd() * UBound(shoe)) + 1
J = shoe(N) = shoe(X)
shoe(N) = shoe(X)
shoe(X) = J
Next
```

If I put another for loop around this and run it an additional 1000+ times I get the results I'm looking for, but it runs far too slow for a 1M hand sim.

Anyone know of any solutions?

Edit:

Also tried this code. The shuffle seems pretty good but its slow.

```
For i = 1 To 2000
c1 = Int(101 * Rnd)
c2 = Int(101 * Rnd)
temp = shoe(c1)
shoe(c1) = shoe(c2)
shoe(c2) = temp
Next i
```

Comment: If you are pulling from a shoe with 1M cards, why even bother with sorting through 19230.7692307692 decks? The laws of large numbers should prove that the cards will be random enough if simply generated on-the-fly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear:

I'm pulling from a shoe of 104 cards (2 decks). I'm playing one hand of blackjack, recording the results, then rebuilding and reshuffling the shoe for another hand. Repeating that process 1M times.

Comment: Could you just rebuild a random deck with each iteration and avoid shuffling altogether?

Comment: Possibly. 


Right now the code is set up to play a specific hand. i.e. I force the player to have a 10 and a 5, and force the dealer to have a 7 face up. 

To achieve this I remove those cards from the shoe then shuffle. I'm not sure how removing specific cards from the shoe without then performing a shuffle would affect the outcome, unless I could also randomly remove the cards selected initially. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Is this done in Excel? How do you define what is what in the deck?

Comment: To get your shuffle right, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle - BUT your bigger problem is that a deck of 52 cards has `52!` = `80658175170943878571660636856403766975289505440883277824000000000000` different permutations, but Excel VBA's built-in random number generator [apparently has only `2^24` = `16777216`](http://blog.richpollock.com/2014/08/randomness-in-excel/) possible states, so you'll only ever see a vanishingly small proportion of the number of possible hands. Two areas of research for you there.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your algorithm, the built-in EXCEL RNG is not suitable for running large number simulations. Also 1M shoe sim is meaningless for Blackjack, and Excel is really not suitable for these sims. You are better off using C++

Comment: The question describes using a shoe of 104 cards but running a simulation 1 million times. I've done plenty of Monte Carlo simulations in Excel VBA with runs in the millions. If a C++ simulation takes just one extra hour to develop you might have to run your program hundreds of times to realize a net gain in programmer time. You don't have enough context to make such a sweeping statement.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am sorry but I can't agree, blackjack is a game with large variance, to get accurate expectation values you will need to run at least a billion hand simulation or use combinatorial analysis. One million hands is nowhere close . Why don't you try to run 2 billion empty loops in VBA (takes 12s on my machine), in 12s my Blackjack simulator runs a 2 billion hand simulation. VBA is simply not designed for large number simulations.

Comment: @Jeanno But -- you don't really know what OP is trying to do. For one thing, they might be a hobbyist programmer who is doing it as a learning experience. Or it could be a prototype. When I first learned about evolutionary algorithms I wrote a VBA program to evolve magic squares. My VBA program was never able to get anything larger than 10x10 squares so at some stage I switched to C (and got much larger squares), but the experience I gained with VBA was invaluable. I often use VBA as a prototyping language since I like how easy it is to dump output to the sheet and generate graphs.

Comment: You don't need to run 2B iterations for a single hand. I'm running 1M iterations per hand combination which is more than sufficient. You'll come within .01% of the actual expectation number every time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can randomize the initial decks of cards each game? Below uses .NET's Collection Array. Hope it explains by itself.

When you take the **i'th** Card from below code, you need to `oCardsAvailable.Remove i`. I don't know how random it is, but I think it's enough. Run the `TestShuffle` list out some shuffled cards.

```
' Spade: 1 | Heart: 2 | Club: 3 | Diamond: 4
' Index: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
' Card:  A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J  Q  K
' CardID: abcc
' a = Deck Number
' b = Symbol
' cc = Card (A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K)
Option Explicit

Dim oCardsAvailable As Object

Sub StartGame(ByVal lCol As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim iDecks As Long, iCardsPerDeck As Long, MaxCount As Long
    Dim iDeck As Integer, iCard As Integer, iSymbol As Integer, CardID As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    ' Initialize
    If Not oCardsAvailable Is Nothing Then
        oCardsAvailable.Clear
        Set oCardsAvailable = Nothing
    End If
    Set oCardsAvailable = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    oCardsAvailable.capacity = iCardsPerDeck * iDecks
    iCardsPerDeck = Range("B1").Value
    iDecks = Range("B2").Value
    MaxCount = iCardsPerDeck * iDecks
    lRow = 9
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow - 1, lCol).Value = lCol
    ' Randomly add the cards to oCardsAvailable
    Do
        iDeck = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, iDecks) * 1000 ' Shift to 4th digit
        iSymbol = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 4) * 100 ' Shift to 3rd digit
        iCard = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 13) ' Card is last 2 digits
        CardID = iDeck + iSymbol + iCard
        If Not oCardsAvailable.contains(CardID) Then
            oCardsAvailable.Add CardID
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, lCol).Value = CardID
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If
    Loop Until oCardsAvailable.Count = MaxCount        
End Sub

Sub TestShuffle()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        StartGame i
    Next
End Sub
```

Sample output:
[image: SampleOutput]

Answer (score 0):

To make your algorithm run fast in `Excel` using `VBA` try this..

1. At the beginning of your VBA code put this line:

   `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
2. At the end of your VBA code put this line:

   `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

This will bring noticeable speed in performance!